# Careers 2.0 "More jobs"-link has clear text JavaScript. Joke, or mistake?

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

[image]

When looking at the page source it looks like this might be on purpose, but looking at it through the browser it just looks weird. Joke or mistake?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Thanks! It's been fixed. Not a joke. :)